# Remote Desktop Connection: Access Denied

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I have remote desktop connection enabled.  I've added my self and the Administrator account.  When I try to login remotely I get:

When I try logging to remote desktop via localhost I get access denied error.  The same occurs when I try remotely, except it says "username or password is not correct"

The terminal server is running, I checked this in services.

I am using the exact same username/password combo for both the local and remote logins.  I can log on the physical machine just fine using the password/username combos.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you are actually on the domain!

I got 'er fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting machinename\username or domainname\username as the login. This is also the same thing with Win7 that I have seen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan!  Just a heads up this is a different machine than earlier.  That didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Is this server a domain controller?

Comment: Dan,

Yeah it is.  I just checked and I can't log on to the domain nor ping the fully qualified.

Comment: What services need to be running for the DC to be working.

Comment: I checked and all the services seem to be up that windows requires....DNS and then all the AD related services as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Group Policy key:
Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Local Policies/User Rights Assignment

There are 2 subkeys that may be of interest:
Allow Logon through Terminal Services
Deny Logon through Terminal Services

Comment: See my comments to Dan.  I don't think that not being able to login remotely is the problem, but rather a symptom of the problem.

Thanks!